# Cannot go back to the previous fragment onBackPressed in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I am creating a tutorial project. In my project, there are so many fragments and  there is only one activity for that fragment. So when I press the back the button, application always exit. So it does not make any sense for user.

So what I want to do is, I would like to go back to previous fragment if it exists when user press the back button. So I found so many identical question on stackoverflow. All the answers say to do like this. To go back to previous fragment in Activity.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

So this is how I override back button listener in my activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if ( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return;
        }
    }
```

But it is not working when I press the back button. Is this correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace / add fragment, did you addToBackStack?

Demo :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).replace(R.id.app_bar_main_container, YOUR_FRAGMENT,YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
```

YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG needs to be unique for each fragment to be able to go back to all previous fragments.

Comment: No. I do only this ?Please can I get a simple code of how to do it?

Comment: Do I need to work with FRAGMENT_TAG when I try to go back to previous fragment ?

Comment: Moreover. Fragment Tag needs to be unique for each fragment  ?

Comment: If simple, you can bypass this FRAGMENT_TAG .FRAGMENT_TAG use for check current Fragment name. .addToBackStack(null);